# Как получить значение переменной в другом классе?Java

Tags: java

Есть 2 класса.
вот первый:

```
    package sample;


import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.CheckBox;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;

public class InputController {

    public double k;
   // public double l;

    @FXML
    private ResourceBundle resources;

    @FXML
    private URL location;

    @FXML
    private MenuItem Input;

    @FXML
    private MenuItem Show;

    @FXML
    private MenuItem Exit;

    @FXML
    private TextField x1;

    @FXML
    private TextField x2;

    @FXML
    private TextField y1;

    @FXML
    private TextField y2;

    @FXML
    private CheckBox length;

    @FXML
    private CheckBox koef;

    @FXML
    private Button butt;

    @FXML
    private AnchorPane In;

    @FXML
    void initialize() {



        Show.setOnAction(event -> {
            double X1 = Double.parseDouble((x1.getText()));
            double Y1 = Double.parseDouble(y1.getText());
            double X2 = Double.parseDouble(x2.getText());
            double Y2 = Double.parseDouble(y2.getText());


            if (length.isSelected()) {
                ShowController len = new ShowController();
             double  l = Math.sqrt(Math.pow((X2 - X1), 2) + Math.pow((Y2 - Y1), 2));// ОБРАТИТЕ ВНИМАНИЕ  НА ЭТУ ПЕРЕМЕННУЮ
               len.setLength(l);



            }

            if (koef.isSelected()) {
                k = (Y2 - Y1) / (X2 - X1);

            }


            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
            loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("/sample/Show.fxml"));
            try {
                loader.load();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Parent root = loader.getRoot();
            Stage stage = new Stage();
            stage.setScene(new Scene(root));
            stage.showAndWait();


        });

        Exit.setOnAction(actionEvent -> {
            System.exit(0);
        });

    }





}
```

Вот второй:

```
package sample;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import org.w3c.dom.ls.LSOutput;

public class ShowController {

   Double length;

    @FXML
    private ResourceBundle resources;

    @FXML
    private URL location;

    @FXML
    private MenuItem Input;

    @FXML
    private MenuItem Show;

    @FXML
    private MenuItem Exit;

    @FXML
    private Button buttt;

    @FXML
    private TextField len;

    @FXML
    private TextField koef;


    public Double getLength() {
        return length;
    }

    public void setLength(Double length) {
        this.length = length;

    }




    @FXML
    void initialize() {




        //____________________________________________________
        Input.setOnAction(actionEvent -> {



            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
            loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("/sample/Input.fxml"));
            try {
                loader.load();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Parent root = loader.getRoot();
            Stage stage = new Stage();
            stage.setScene(new Scene(root));
            stage.showAndWait();

        });

        Exit.setOnAction(actionEvent -> {
            System.exit(0);

        });
//____________________________________________________________________________

    }
}
```

Нужно чтобы значение переменной "l" из первого класса(InputController) можно было вывести в void initialize() во втором(ShowController). 
Я многое перепробовал, всегда выводило "null"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

в первом классе:

```java
public static double l; .
```

```java
//initialize
this.l = Math.sqrt(Math.pow((X2 - X1), 2) + Math.pow((Y2 - Y1), 2));//наша переменная
len.setLength(this.l);
```

во втором классе:

```java
//initialize
double l = InputController.l; //доступ к нашей переменной
//сначала требуется выполнить метод initialize из первого класса, а затем из второго
```

Также проверьте выполнение условия

```java
if (length.isSelected())
```

из первого класса

Comment: не вышло. 
я так понял этот метод всегда должен быть void, т.к. он отвечает за работу окна приложения

Comment: Тогда создайте `public static double` переменную в первом классе, занесите результат в нее, а затем считайте во втором классе.

Comment: Я не совсем понял как это сделать. Я должен в 'public static double' переменную занести результат подсчета переменной "l", а вот что считать во втором классе? Можете объяснить поподробней?

Comment: Получилось, спасибо огромное!